# Get last 6 months name in Array

Tags: excel, vba

Want to get list of last 6 months name in array mon but get error as Subscript out of range at line

```
mon(X) = val
```

Any idea where i am wrong,output shoule be like

```
mon = ("DecWK1","DecWK2","DecWK3","DecWK4","Dec","JanWK1","JanWK2","JanWK3","JanWK4","Jan",.......)
```

Main Code

```
Sub ColorRows()

Dim mon() As Variant, MonthName() As Variant, X As Long
Dim val As String

X = 0
ReDim Preserve mon(X)

MonthName = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

Dim monName As String

For i = -6 To 0
  '  MsgBox i
    monName = Format(DateAdd("M", i, Now), "MMMM")
   ' MsgBox sMonth_Name


   For Each element In MonthName
   ReDim Preserve mon(0 To X)
        If InStr(monName, element) Then
            For j = 1 To 4
                val = element & "WK" & j
                mon(X) = val
                X = X + 1
            Next j

            mon(X) = element
            X = X + 1
        End If

    Next element
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You do know that `MonthName()` is a built-in function in Access, yes?

Comment: No, sorry new to VBA

Comment: In the inner loop you increase `X` without also extending the `mon` array, so that explains the error. But there are several issues with your code. Are you assuming a month has always 4 weeks?

Comment: yes month has always 4 weeks, as 'X' is icremented  we are using the 'X' on 'mon(X)' so isnt 'mon' also incremented ?

Comment: If you already know that your array will always have 6*5 elements, why not Dim it with 30 elements?

Comment: @Andre it can be from 32 to 35 elements last 6 months 30 elements and current month current week going on which will consist of 2 to 5 elements, so elements not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `ReDim` your array, you aren't taking into account the new elements to be added.

Write:

```
 ReDim Preserve mon(0 To X + 4)
```

instead.